# how can I insert data from multiple select box ID into database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, insert, multipleselection

I have a multiple select box in my view, I am using the Codeigniter framework. I want to insert the values that consist of ID's in my multiple selection box.

I get the values from my multiple select in controller, using this:

```
$diagnosis = $this->input->post('tdiagnosis');
var_dump($diagnosis);
```

when I var_dump the value of `$diagnosis` I get this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

I want to loop these values to be inserted one by one into my database, here is what I've done:

```
public function finish_checkup($patient_id,$queue_id,$checkup_id,$clinic_id) {
   $diagnosis = $this->input->post('tdiagnosis');
        for($i = 0;$i < count($diagnosis); $i++) {
            $data4 = array (
                'diagnosis' => $diagnosis[i],
                'check_up_id' => $checkup_id
            );
            $insert = $this->Mymodel->savetodb($data4);
        }
}
```

why do I get this error?

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Use of undefined constant i -
>   assumed 'i'

Comment: you forgot the $ in $diagnosis[$i] ;)

Comment: first change this $data4 = array (
                'diagnosis' => $diagnosis[i],
                'check_up_id' => $checkup_id
            ); change to   $data4 = array (
                'diagnosis' => $diagnosis[$i],
                'check_up_id' => $checkup_id
            );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it:

```
'diagnosis' => $diagnosis[i],
```

to

```
'diagnosis' => $diagnosis[$i],
```

you forget to add `$` with the variable `i`, that's why the notice `Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i'`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function finish_checkup($patient_id,$queue_id,$checkup_id,$clinic_id) {
    $diagnosis = $this->input->post('tdiagnosis');
    $data['check_up_id'] = $check_up_id;
    foreach ($diagnosis as $diagnos) {
        $data['diagnosis'] = $diagnos;
        $insert = $this->Mymodel->savetodb($data);
    }
```

}